# Doing repeated Addition in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a databade table as follows

```
id  A
1   2
2   4
3   5
4   9
```

I want the result to show as below by doing repeated addition

```
A   B
2   2
4   6
5   11
9   20
```

Comment: Can you try formatting your table + results using the source code `{ }` button? That would make it much easier to understand your question.

Comment: this is a formatted version of the challenge

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d66f6/1

```
SELECT a,
 IF(@b IS NULL, @b:=a, @b:=@b+a) as B
FROM table1
```

Comment: An ORDER BY clause is required. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20234/1

Comment: That is up to you to post your own answer, or comment mine. But not to fix my one. Don't you agree?

Comment: No. I don't agree. SO encourages improvements/corrections.

Comment: Ok. No comments then

Comment: Thank you Alex and Strawberry

Comment: We should point out that with this usage *user-defined variables* in a single statement, MySQL does *not* guarantee the behavior we observe. Also, the behavior of this statement is influenced by the current value of the user defined variable `@b` when the statement begins executing. Also, this statement does *not* guarantee what order the rows will be returned. The query provided in this answer can be considered to "work" in that we observe that it returns a resultset that matches the specification, when `@b` is undefined or initialized to 0, and  if we don't care about the order of the rows.

Comment: We should also note that it could easily be tweaked to work just fine. Indeed, it would perform better than my own effort.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, we're supposed to ask you what you've tried, but anyway...

```
SELECT x.a
     , SUM(y.a) b 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
```